# Can Globalization Work Without Localization in Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, reflection, locale

According to MSDN `Globalization is the process of designing and developing a software product that functions in multiple cultures/locales." "Localization is the process of adopting a globalized application, which you have already processed for localizability, to a particular culture/locale`

But my question is can a web application work in which only globalization is defined not localization?

any theoretical example will be welcome...

Answer (score 0):

Globalization is a process -- do this, that, and the other thing, and you are in the *process* of globalizing -- not something you define, per se.